# C# Outlook - Call Rejected By Callee

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, calendar

Trying to add an event to Outlook calendar through my event registration app using asp.net/C#. Getting call was rejected by callee error when trying to initialize (line 1). How do I overcome this issue?

Error:
"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80010001 Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))."

```
Outlook.Application outlookapp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = outlookapp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
appt.Subject = er.Event.Name;
appt.MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
appt.Location = er.Event.LocationName;
appt.Start = er.Event.StartTime;
appt.End = er.Event.EndTime;
appt.Recipients.ResolveAll();
appt.Display(false);
appt.Save();
```

Comment: Are you building to the same architecture as the machine you're running on? Meaning if you're on a 64 bit OS, are you compiling to x64?

Comment: I have the active solution platform set to Any CPU.

Comment: I generally wouldn't use that setting for any real reason. Set it to x64 or x86, whatever platform you're running on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot use Outlook from a service (such as IIS).

Secondly, even if your code worked, you'd end up creating an appointment and displaying  (!) it locally on the server machine, where there isn't anybody to see it.

Create an iCal file and provide a link to the user - the ics file will be opened on the client machine using Outlook and the user will be able to save it.

Comment: I have a problem, I am trying to read all emails from outlook (exchange) , it works fine locally but deploys it on` iis` ,it retruns an exception . I just created a console app and it can connect and read emails but in asp mvc project it can not . is it possible ?

Comment: You cannot and should not use any Office apps (Outlook included) from a service (such as IIS).

Comment: Because it is a UI app that is not designed to run in a service. Don't try to make it work. It will fail. If not today, then tomorrow.

Comment: Use a different API - EWS, Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), Redemption (any language - it wraps Extended MAPI), etc.

Comment: I tried to use EWS, but I can not get just unread emails. I think it does not have this kind of filter, does it?

Comment: Of course it does. If you are having problems with it, please start a new thread,

Answer (score 0):

Server-side Automation of Office is not supported

> Developers can use Automation in Microsoft Office to build custom solutions that use the capabilities and the features that are built into the Office product. Although such programmatic development can be implemented on a client system with relative ease, **a number of complications can occur if Automation takes place from server-side code such as Microsoft Active Server Pages (ASP), ASP.NET, DCOM, or a Windows NT service.**

See : https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/257757