# Error trying to create outlook taskitem in web server app (asp.net mvc5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, outlook

- Using VS 2013 on MVC 5 project.

I' trying to send a task to outlook from an email. I've read several posts about and so far I was able to compile the following code, but it fails when trying to create the TaskItem.

```
        public void SendTask()
    {
        // This creates OK
        var OutlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

        // RUN TIME error error here
        Outlook.TaskItem task = OutlookApp.Session.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olTaskItem) as Outlook.TaskItem;

        task.Subject = "Tax Preparation";
        task.StartDate = DateTime.Parse("4/29/2016 8:00 AM");
        task.DueDate = DateTime.Parse("4/30/2016 8:00 AM");
        task.Assign();
        task.Recipients.Add("support@example.com");
        task.Recipients.ResolveAll();
        task.Send();
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide more than just "it fails" and "error here". Post the exception message here, and the inner ones if necessary.

Comment: @Xiaoy312  Message = "Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))"   The inner exception is null.  Now I read that it is not possible to send, or just create a message file in asp.net. So I don't know anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Outlook - Call Rejected By Callee](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894577/c-sharp-outlook-call-rejected-by-callee)

Comment: @Xiaoy312 That doesn't even have the same error code.

Comment: @Rob Yes, the error code is different, but read the answers in that question : "a number of complications can occur if Automation takes place from server-side code such as Microsoft Active Server Pages (ASP), ASP.NET, DCOM, or a Windows NT service." It is simply not supported.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 I followed the link you suggested and although the answer was not there, it led me to the solution in another post. So, to close this thread I will accept your comment as answer if you post it.